# Python scipy overload _stats function for beta distribution

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I need to overload the `_stats` function for my beta distribution. This is my current code:

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import scipy.stats as st

class CustomBeta(st.rv_continuous):
    def _stats(self, a, b):
        # will add own code here
        mn = a * 1.0 / (a + b)
        var = (a * b * 1.0) / (a + b + 1.0) / (a + b) ** 2.0
        g1 = 2.0 * (b - a) * sqrt((1.0 + a + b) / (a * b)) / (2 + a + b)
        g2 = 6.0 * (a ** 3 + a ** 2 * (1 - 2 * b) + b ** 2 * (1 + b) - 2 * a * b * (2 + b))
        g2 /= a * b * (a + b + 2) * (a + b + 3)
        return mn, var, g1, g2

dist = beta(4, 6)
print dist.rvs()  # works fine


dist = CustomBeta(4, 6)
print dist.rvs()  # crashes
```

Getting `_rvs()` from my custom object gives me a long stacktrace and an error

`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with overloading `_stats`. The same behavior is caused simply by

```
class CustomBeta(st.rv_continuous):
    pass

dist = CustomBeta(4, 6)
print(dist.rvs())  # crashes
```

The [documentation of `rv_continuous`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html) states that

> New random variables can be defined by subclassing the rv_continuous class and re-defining **at least** the `_pdf` or the `_cdf` method.

You will need to provide at least one of these methods to compute the probability density function (pdf) or the cumulative probability density function(cdf).

Furthermore,

> [`rv_continuous`] cannot be used directly as a distribution.

It is used as follows:

```
class CustomBetaGen(st.rv_continuous):
    ...

CustomBeta = CustomBetaGen(name='CustomBeta')

dist = CustomBeta(4, 6)
```

Finally, `rvs.()` does not seem to work properly for the beta distribution if you do not provide a `_rvs` method.

Putting everything together and stealing the appropriate methods from the beta distribution:

```
from scipy.stats import beta
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np

class CustomBetaGen(st.rv_continuous):
    def _cdf(self, x, a, b):
        return beta.cdf(x, a, b)
    def _pdf(self, x, a, b):
        return beta.pdf(x, a, b)
    def _rvs(self, a, b):
        return beta.rvs(a, b)
    def _stats(self, a, b):
        # will add own code here
        mn = a * 1.0 / (a + b)
        var = (a * b * 1.0) / (a + b + 1.0) / (a + b) ** 2.0
        g1 = 2.0 * (b - a) * np.sqrt((1.0 + a + b) / (a * b)) / (2 + a + b)
        g2 = 6.0 * (a ** 3 + a ** 2 * (1 - 2 * b) + b ** 2 * (1 + b) - 2 * a * b * (2 + b))
        g2 /= a * b * (a + b + 2) * (a + b + 3)
        return mn, var, g1, g2

CustomBeta = CustomBetaGen(name='CustomBeta')

dist = beta(4, 6)
print(dist.rvs())  # works fine
print(dist.stats())  # (array(0.4), array(0.021818181818181816))

dist = CustomBeta(4, 6)
print(dist.rvs())  # works fine
print(dist.stats())  # (array(0.4), array(0.021818181818181816))
```

Comment: I get this error, AttributeError: 'beta_gen' object has no attribute '_size'

Comment: @n00b I also got this strange error but forgot to fix it in the code. Try changing `return beta._rvs(a, b)` to `return beta.rvs(a, b)`.